# Truffle migrate and truffle install error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, installation, migrate, truffle

I keep getting this error. When I try `truffle migrate --reset`

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\merta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: []
    }
```

I am getting the error.

When I try to install truffle, I get the following error via yarn or npm

> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
> gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
> gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
> gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
> gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
> gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
> gyp ERR! find VS - not found
> gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
> gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
> gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
> gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> gyp ERR! find VS
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstu
> dio.js:122:47)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib
> \find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
> gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\
> \node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\merta\\Downloads\\Compressed\\fr
> ontend_base_dapp-main\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sql
> ite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\merta\\Downloads\\Compressed\\frontend_base_dapp-main\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\b
> inding\\node-v93-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\merta\Downloads\Compressed\frontend_base_dapp-main\node_modules\sqlite3
> gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
> gyp ERR! not ok
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\merta\Downloads\Compr
> essed\frontend_base_dapp-main\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --
> module_path=C:\Users\merta\Downloads\Compressed\frontend_base_dapp-main\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --
> napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\merta\Downloads\Compressed\frontend_base_dapp-main\node_modules
> \node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
> Done in 367.51s.

Node.js, VS, Python etc. all apps are installed. I tried with VScode and Atom but I get the same error.

Comment: I am also unable to install truffle using 'npm install -g truffle ' and have the same error. But the thing is i was able to install it on another laptop without an issue

Comment: The error still persists.

Comment: I solved it by installing previous version of node (v14.15.0). Then i installed truffle and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Managed to solve first uninstalling truffle 'npm uninstall -g truffle' (check every single route/folder on your sistem related) then using previous node version v14.17.3 to install it again.
Make sure you follow all the process being the system admin or having permission.